# SetTimeout and serialport events - order of code execution

Tags: node.js, settimeout, node-serialport

I have a code which is consequently performed in the following order.

result:

START APP,

After 5000 [ms],

Port is open

Why, I have to wait for the port to be opened until settimeout function is called?

```
const serial = require('serialport');

var mySerialPort = new serial("COM5", {
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false,
    //autoOpen: false,
});


console.log("START APP");

//Events
mySerialPort.on('open', function() {
    console.log("Port is open");
});

setTimeout(() => console.log("After 5000 [ms]"), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread with this error:  https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport/issues/1751. Topic can close.